# Having output issues with python; loop totals and averages

Tags: python, loops, nested

Having a few output issues with my nested loop, normally I use `break` to add some lines into my code or `print()`

When I use `print()` within my code my output looks like I am typing totals on a new line all together that is not what I want

Following is a picture of my current output and where I need a blank line;

[image]

Second thing:

My code is not calculating the information correctly to find the total and average rainfall per month.

code follows

```
def main():

#define accumulators
monthRain = 0
year = 0
monthTotal = 0
months = 0
total = 0 

#get # of years
year = int(input("Enter the number of years to collect data for: "))

#blank line
print()

#define month total befor it is changed below with year + 1
monthTotal = year * 12

#define how many months per year
months = 12

#Find average rainfall per month
for year in range(year):
    #accumulator for rain per month
    total = 0
    #get rainfall per month
    print('Next you will enter 12 months of rainfall data for year', year + 1)
    for month in range(months):
        print("Enter the rainfall for month", month + 1, end='')
        monthRain = float(input(': '))

        #add monthly raingfall to accumulator
        total += monthRain
        average = total / monthTotal

#total months of data 
print('You have entered data for', monthTotal,'months')

#blank line
print()

#total rainfall
print('The total rainfall for the collected months is:', total)
print('The average monthly rainfall for the collected months is:', average)


main()
```

Comment: you are looping over years and months. do you want a yearly total and monthly average over 1 year? Or a total of all the years and the monthly average over all the years? The correct answer depends on knowing what you want to do. It is not clear.

Comment: total and average of all months based on what the user input for years is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Following is a picture of my current output and where I need a blank line*

In order to get a blank line before `You have entered data for`, add `\n` at the start of the string. It represents new line. Hence your print statement should be as:

```
print("\nYou have entered data for")
```

> *my code is not calculating the information correctly to find the total and average rainfall per month.*

On dividing two `int` values, python returns `int` as by default excluding the float precision. In order to get the `float` value, conver either of numerator or denomenator to `float`. Example:

```
>>> 1/5
0  # <-- Ignored float value as between two int
>>> 1/float(5)
0.2  #<-- Float value to conversion of denomenator to float
```

Also, in `average = total / monthTotal`, I believe that the `average` is need for per month basis. It should be `month` instead of `monthTotal`. Because `total` will be having the sum of rain for `month` months. In order to get average of rain in `month` months, your equation should be:

```
average = total / float(month)
```

Comment: your comment about integer division is only true in Python 2. ```1/5=0.2``` in Python 3. To get integer division back in Python 3 you have to do ```1//5=0```

Comment: the \n worked (THANK YOU)



The total rainfall for the collected months is: < this is where I am getting messed up it is counting 64 when the actual total is 67? for year one and 131 total for both years.....

How do I add the 2 years together into one?



The average monthly rainfall for the collected months is: << this is total rainfall over 24 months /divided/ by  # of months based on year input by user......  so if it was a "2 year" input then that would be total rainfall / 24 months makes the total average formula correct